# Retrieving email from outlook with imap_fetchbody() broken

Tags: php, imap, php-imap

I have been using [php-imap-client](https://github.com/SSilence/php-imap-client) for some time and has always worked great. The issue is that recently it seems to break with fetching email from outlook/office365 mailboxes now  and I can't pinpoint the issue. As far as I know it seems to be breaking with `imap_fetchbody()` but that is as far as I get.

`getMessages()` basically does not work and I was wondering if anyone has come across this yet and maybe can shed some light to a solution to fix it.

Things like `countMessages` and `countUnreadMessages` work fine but once you try get the email contents that is where it breaks.

```
$overallMessages = $imap->countMessages();
$unreadMessages = $imap->countUnreadMessages();
```

**Here is all my code**

```
$mailbox = $row['imap_server_address'];
$username = $row['imap_username'];
$password = $row['imap_password'];
$encryption = Imap::ENCRYPT_SSL; // TLS OR NULL accepted

// Open connection
try{
    $imap = new Imap($mailbox, $username, $password, $encryption);
    // You can also check out example-connect.php for more connection options

}catch (ImapClientException $error){
    echo $error->getMessage().PHP_EOL; // You know the rule, no errors in production ...
    die(); // Oh no :( we failed
}

// Select the folder INBOX
$imap->selectFolder('INBOX');

// Count the messages in current folder
$overallMessages = $imap->countMessages();
$unreadMessages = $imap->countUnreadMessages();

// Fetch all the messages in the current folder
echo "This echos fine";
$emails = $imap->getMessages();
echo "This does not echo";
var_dump($emails);
```

I can connect to the server just fine. I can select the INBOX, I can get overall messages and as well as unread. `var_dump($email)` produces nothing. And there are unread emails in the inbox.

When I `echo` after `$emails = $imap->getMessages();` nothing is echo'd to the screen so something is breaking here.

Comment: Define breaks.  Provide input, output, code...

Comment: I added my whole code. There is no output that I can see.